# Layered-List bitmap padding

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating a custom background with an arrow on the right. I can't seem to control the padding of the drawable; it is right next to the right edge. I would like to control the offset from the right. I've tried adding `android:right` and other `<margin...` attributes with no effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#bbbbbb"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" />
        <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
        <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap 
       android:gravity="right"
       android:src="@drawable/btn_dropdown_arrow" />
</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the shape using below code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#bbbbbb" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#000000" />

    <corners android:radius="5dip" />

</shape>
```

Then apply this to the background of the View. In that view we have attribute like `drawable_right`.

```
<android:drawable_right="@drawable/btn_dropdown_arrow">
```

Comment: No luck. I'll have to try something else.

Comment: What exactly u want.. drop down arrow to the right of background shape  or inside background

Comment: align right puts it all the way to the edge. I just want some padding on the bitmap drawable to i can move it to left a little

Comment: Give some padding-right to the view. If u want space between the text and drawable use drawable-padding.

Answer (score 1):

Use of a `right` inset attribute in the `bitmap`'s `item` tag will give the bitmap padding on the right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#bbbbbb"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" />
        <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
        <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:right="10dp">
    <bitmap 
       android:gravity="right"
       android:src="@drawable/btn_dropdown_arrow" />
</item>
```